# Base64.DEFAULT authentication doesn't work on old Android devices (2.3)

Tags: android, android-bootstrap

I use the http://www.androidbootstrap.com/ classes for authentication and so on.

It works perfect on my 4.0 Android device, but on my older Android devices it gives me a 403 error.

I'm very sure that the login data is correct so it has something to do with a bug in Android 2.3?

**UPDATE**

Base64 problem.. just changed to NO_WRAP and it worked!

Maybe someone can explain?

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with my own writed code, somehow the **Base64.DEFAULT** returns a 403 error **Base64.NO_WRAP** worked for me!